# Hadoop about HA, stop one active node,but another standby can not convert to active state

Tags: hadoop, high-availability

I have configured core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml about HA. And test it on website. I stoped one active node(hadoop-daemon.sh stop namenode), but another standby can not convert to active state.The standby node became active state when I restart the node. So the HA does not work.I do not know why.

Comment: Did you config the zookeeper and automatic-failover? Did you see the DFSZKFailoverController and QuorumPeerMain in your jps out put?Did you check the zkfc log?

Comment: I configure the zookeeper and automatic-failover and DFSZKFailoverController and QuorumPeerMain in my jps. But I did not check my zkfc log.

Comment: check the zkfc log to see if there is any errors

Comment: You are right. it writed "EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x4c265b32bc0006, likely client has closed socket" in zkfc log. But i do not know how i solve the question.